# Binding to child properties from parent control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.Control1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="StackPanelInsideUserControl">
        <Label />
        <TextBox Name="TextBoxInsideUserControl" Text="Initial Text" />
        <Button Content="OK" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And I'm trying to bind to the Text property of the TextBoxInsideUserControl TextBox from a its parent like in:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <local:Control1 StackPanelInsideUserControl.TextBoxInsideUserControl.Text="{Binding SomeText}" />
</Grid>
```

How can I achieve that? Does xaml allow us to do that?

Comment: No, not really. You should define a dependency property on that UserControl, bind that to the Text of the TextBox. Then you can access the text outside of the UserControl via that dependency property.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'm using a third party framework in the place of that UserControl, I'll ask their support. But now I know the xaml way of doing this. Mind posting this as answer then I can mark and give you the credits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, the comment as answer:

No, not really. You should define a **dependency property** on that `UserControl`, bind that to the Text of the `TextBox`. Then you can access the text outside of the UserControl via that dependency property.